# TypeError: the first argument must be callable in scheduler library

Tags: python

I am getting the following error while running scheduler library. I did go through similar question and answers but somehow not able to identify the root cuase the error. Could some help where I am going wrong?

> *TypeError: the first argument must be callable*

```
import schedule
    import time


class Scheduler():

    def trigger_testsuite(self):
        print("I am working as expected.")

    def scheule_a_job(self, type="Secs", interval=5):

        if (type == "Mins"):
            schedule.every(interval).minutes.do(self.trigger_testsuite())

        if (type == "Secs"):
            schedule.every(interval).seconds.do(self.trigger_testsuite())

        if (interval == "Hrs"):
            schedule.every().hour.do(self.trigger_testsuite())

        if (interval == "Daily"):
            schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(self.trigger_testsuite())

        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run = Scheduler()
    run.scheule_a_job()
```

**TraceBack:-**

```
I am working as expected.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo/Scheduler.py", line 31, in <module>
    run.scheule_a_job()
  File "foo/Scheduler.py", line 16, in scheule_a_job
    schedule.every(interval).seconds.do(self.trigger_testsuite())
  File "foo\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 440, in do
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not include the parentheses in the function passed to:

```
schedule.every(interval).minutes.do()
```

So,  this this line:

```
schedule.every(interval).minutes.do(self.trigger_testsuite())
```

Should be:

```
schedule.every(interval).minutes.do(self.trigger_testsuite)
```

And same for all the others. Final code becomes:

```
import schedule
    import time


class Scheduler():

    def trigger_testsuite(self):
        print("I am working as expected.")

    def scheule_a_job(self, type="Secs", interval=5):

        if (type == "Mins"):
            schedule.every(interval).minutes.do(self.trigger_testsuite)

        if (type == "Secs"):
            schedule.every(interval).seconds.do(self.trigger_testsuite)

        if (interval == "Hrs"):
            schedule.every().hour.do(self.trigger_testsuite)

        if (interval == "Daily"):
            schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(self.trigger_testsuite)

        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run = Scheduler()
    run.scheule_a_job()
```