# Using schedule module to reming me to drink water every ten seconds

Tags: python, schedule

I am using schedule module to remind me to drink water every ten seconds

```
import schedule


def remindDrink():
    print("Drink Water")
while True:
    schedule.every().day.at("16:35").do(remindDrink())
```

So the problem here is that the task gets executed, but immedieately, not at the given time, and VSCode throws a weird error at me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Code\Python Code\randomModule.py", line 12, in <module>
    schedule.every().day.at("16:31").do(sendNotification())
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 625, in do
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
PS E:\Code\Python Code>
```

This is the error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you schedule it in a while loop? You only need to do it once and it will run at the selected schedule.

Comment: You should put schedule.run_pending() in the while loop instead. Refer to https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-every-x-minute

Comment: its what this question showed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575348/how-to-make-a-program-remind-me-in-a-specific-time-everyday-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same module different approach, I personally prefer this approach because it keeps my work **clean**, easy to **read** and to **understand** at your first glance and ofcourse easy to **refactor**.

```py
from schedule import every, repeat, run_pending
import time

@repeat(every().day.at("16:35"))
def remindDrink():
    print("Drink Water")

while True:
    run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Your broken code fixed:**
Your broken code is fixed below, now the choice is yours, you can either use the above code or this:

```py
import schedule
import time

def remindDrink():
    print("Drink Water")

schedule.every().day.at("16:35").do(remindDrink)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: does absolutely nothing

Comment: oh wait it worked, i forgot that time has passed since 16:35

Comment: i changed the time of execution, could you also let me know what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Rember you have given it a time **"16:35"** every day. So until then it will not execute, You can change **(every().day.at("16:35"))** to some seconds run to confirm if it works or not.

Comment: Because you didn't include **schedule.run_pending()** to while and also in **do** should only contain function name without **()**

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `()` from `remindDrink()` in the last line inside the `do()` function

Your code should look like this:

```
schedule.every().day.at("16:35").do(remindDrink)
```

Refer back to this question: [TypeError: the first argument must be callable in scheduler library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018745/typeerror-the-first-argument-must-be-callable-in-scheduler-library)

Answer (score 1):

quick thought, shedule....do(), within do() you don't run the function, just put the name of the function inside do.
'''
schedule.every().day.at("16:35").do(remindDrink)
'''