# task scheduler not working for python win32

Tags: python

I am running the following Python code from jupyter and powershell and it is running flawlessly.

When I put this in window scheduler, it doesn't run. It doesn't show any error either. Could you please help solve the problem? Are there better options to schedule my Python code in window?

I am running python 3.10.

My code was running before:

```py
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'dsrigyan@yahoo.com'
mail.Subject = 'data'
# mail.Body = 'data'
mail.HTMLBody = '''<p style="font-family:Corbel">
    Hi Deepa,<br/>  
    Please find the data for yesterday.<br/>
    Let me know if you has any questions.
</p>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
                <p  style="font-family:Corbel">
                    <b>Deepankar Srigyan<br/>               
                    BI &amp; Analytics Manager
                </p>
            '''


attachment  = attachment_file
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

mail.Send()
```

Comment: Did you put in the task scheduler as a .bat targeting the file? Did you use any particular setting?

Comment: The task scheduler logs to the Event Viewer, have you checked that?

Comment: Refer to my previous answer to similar issue  [Use scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73136874/19290081)

Answer (score 1):

See [creating a bat file for python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script) to understand how to launch your script with a .bat file, then launch that via windows scheduler rather than launching the python script directly.